# Кукла и куколка

Tags: омонимы

Что такое кукла, думаю, объяснять не нужно. В то же время куколка - это то, из чего впоследствии вылупляется бабочка, то есть, некое промежуточное звено между гусеницей и, собственно, бабочкой.
Интересно было бы понять, какая связь между этими словами? На первый взгляд я никакой связи не вижу - вряд ли из пластмассовой Барби может вылупиться девица)))))

Answer (score 2):

В словаре Ушакова указано на внешнее сходство со "спелёнутой куколкой". Видимо, речь идёт о небольшой кукле и о старых, "добарбических" способах игры в куклы (с пеленанием дочурки) - внешний вид нехитрых деревенских кукол из пучка травы, вероятно, когда-то и подсказал такое название:
"2. Насекомое в промежуточной стадии своего развития (от личинки до полной зрелости), имеющее в это время вид неподвижной, как бы спеленутой куколки."